# Is there any way to check quality of TRNG at runtime or after installation in application?

Tags: encryption

True random number generator quality can be checked with statistic tests like the NIST suite or DIEHARD suite but after time, how we can check for its durability and whether it still possesses the same quality of randomness ..no temperature effect or hardware trojan-like entity disturbed it.